# Django LiveTestServerCase not using proper settings

Tags: django, selenium

In a Django project I'm using selenium to run some UI tests, using a [`LiveServerTestCase`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/testing/overview/#django.test.LiveServerTestCase).

One of my test cases is failing, and when using the Firefox driver I can see a page throwing "Server Error (500)", which means `DEBUG` is set to `False` which is not the case when I run the local development server.

How is the test server being launched? Why is not using my settings which define `DEBUG = True`?

Other URLs (such as the homepage URL) return fine, so the server is working. But I just don't get why it's not showing debug information, and which settings it's using.

My test case for reference:

```
class LoginTest(LiveServerTestCase):

    @classmethod
    def setUpClass(cls):
        try:
            from selenium.webdriver import PhantomJS
            cls.selenium = PhantomJS()
        except:
            from selenium.webdriver.firefox.webdriver import WebDriver
            cls.selenium = WebDriver()
        super(LoginTest, cls).setUpClass()

    @classmethod
    def tearDownClass(cls):
        cls.selenium.quit()
        super(LoginTest, cls).tearDownClass()

    def test_fb_login(self):
        self.selenium.get('%s%s' % (self.live_server_url, reverse('account_login')))
        # TEST SERVER RETURNS 500 ON THIS URL WITH NO DEBUG INFO
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to [Testing Django Application - Django Documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/testing/overview/#other-test-conditions):

> Regardless of the value of the DEBUG setting in your configuration
>   file, all Django tests run with **DEBUG=False**. This is to ensure that
>   the observed output of your code matches what will be seen in a
>   production setting.

---

It should still be possible to [override this using](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/testing/overview/#overriding-settings):

```
with self.settings(DEBUG=True):
    ...
```

Although I wouldn't recommend it, it can still be useful from time to time. (Thomas Orozco's comment)

Comment: good catch! any idea how I can override this just for test development purposes?

Comment: @YuvalAdam To add to this: it should still be possible to override this using [`with self.settings(DEBUG=True)`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/testing/overview/#overriding-settings). Although I wouldn't recommend it, it can still be useful from time to time.

Comment: @ThomasOrozco, Thank you for comment. I didn't know that. I added your comment in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can also change your settings in TestCase setUp() method.

```
from django.conf import settings

class MyTest(LiveServerTestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        # Change settings here
        settings.DEBUG = True

        # ...
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue and it is possible to override settings with a decorator.

based on your example you would import `override_settings` and place the decorator above the class:

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.test import override_settings

@override_settings(DEBUG=True)
class LoginTest(LiveServerTestCase):

    ...
```

details in [django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/testing/tools/#django.test.override_settings)